# Fluent NHibernate mapping exception (no persister error)

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following code which gives me a mapping exception with no persister error:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(
            c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Main.ConnectionString")))
    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    .BuildSessionFactory();

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var card = new Card {CardType = "Test"};

        session.Save(card);

        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

I have three projects in my solution: `MainApplication` , `Entities` and `EntityMappings`

`MainApp` has a reference to `Entities` and `EntityMappings` has a reference to `Entities`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

The properties are `public`

The exact error message is : `No persister for: TNT_DAL.EntityClasses.Card`

Comment: Can you provide the full exception message please? If I recall correctly it should mention no persister for a particular class or database field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your entity and mapping classes are `public`. Properties for your entities i.e. database fields should be `public virtual`.

Also try specifying the assembly of a mapping class instead of using `GetExecutingAssembly()`, I do vaguely recall experiencing trouble with it when I tried setting up FNH for the first time.

```
.Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CardMap>())
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was that my application did not have a reference to the project which had Mapping Classes